# Unable to connect to EC2 instance from Bastion host on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am not able to connect to ec2 instance from my bastion host. Pretty standard problem that is there online as well but I have tried all of that. I have setup my infra using Terraform.

This is my main.tf :

```
# Configure the AWS provider
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"  # Replace with your desired AWS region
  access_key = ""
  secret_key = ""
}

# Create a VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

# Create a public subnet for the bastion host
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"  # Update with your desired CIDR block
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"   # Update with your desired availability zone
}

# Create a security group for the bastion host
resource "aws_security_group" "bastion_security_group" {
  name        = "bastion-security-group"
  description = "Allow SSH access to bastion host"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]  # Update with your desired source IP range
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    self        = true  # Allow SSH access from within the same security group
  }
}

# Create a security group for the porse instance
resource "aws_security_group" "my_security_group" {
  name        = "my-security-group"
  description = "Allow inbound and outbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]  # Update with your desired source IP range
  }

  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.bastion_security_group.id]  # Allow SSH access from bastion_security_group
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    self        = true  # Allow SSH access from within the same security group
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]  # Update with the desired destination IP range or remove the cidr_blocks to allow all outbound traffic
  }
}

# Create the bastion host instance
resource "aws_instance" "bastion_host" {
  ami                          = "ami-03f65b8614a860c29"  # Replace with the ID of your desired AMI
  instance_type                = "t2.micro"               # Update with your desired instance type
  key_name                     = "bastion_key_pair"       # Replace with your bastion host key pair name
  vpc_security_group_ids       = [aws_security_group.bastion_security_group.id]
  subnet_id                    = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address  = true  # Assign a public IP to the bastion host

  # Additional configuration for the bastion host
  # ...
}

# Create an EC2 instance for the porse microservice
resource "aws_instance" "porse_instance" {
  count                  = var.stop_instance ? 0 : 1
  ami                    = "ami-03f65b8614a860c29"  # Replace with the ID of your desired AMI
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = "bastion_key_pair"  # Replace with your key pair name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.my_security_group.id]
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id

  # You may need to add additional configuration options based on your specific requirements
}

# Create a private subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.0.0/24"  # Update with your desired CIDR block for the private subnet
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"   # Update with your desired availability zone
}

# Create an internet gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "my_internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
}

# Create a route table
resource "aws_route_table" "public_subnet_route" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.my_internet_gateway.id
  }
}

# Associate the route table with the subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_subnet_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_subnet_route.id
}

# Declare variables
variable "stop_instance" {
  description = "Flag to stop or start the EC2 instance"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}
```

I have setup config in ~/.ssh/config to access my bastion and ec2 but when I try to ssh into ec2 via bastion, I get following error :

```
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Everything that I have tried :

Ensured that the security group associated with the porse instance allows incoming SSH traffic (port 22) from the security group associated with the bastion host. Verify that the security group rules have the correct settings and that they permit traffic between the two security groups.

Checked the network ACLs associated with the subnet. Ensure that the network ACL rules allow inbound and outbound SSH traffic (port 22) between the bastion host and the porse instance. Verify that there are no rules blocking the communication between the two instances.

Both are on same subnet so it should work

Instance State and Connectivity: Confirm that both the bastion host and the porse instance are in a running state. Check if you can ping the porse instance from the bastion host using the private IP address. If the ping is successful, it indicates that there is basic network connectivity between the two instances.

ping is failing between the two instances.

Comment: Is there an Outbound (egress) rule for the Security Group on the Bastion instance? Basically, the Bastion security group should allow Inbound port 22 from your computer and Outbound to anywhere (no need to restrict it). The security group on the other instance should allow Inbound port 22 from the Bastion security group.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein . This was the only issue. After adding egress rule it worked. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from John. The solution was adding egress rule to allow outbound to anywhere. I updated my terraform code and it worked.